# How can I get the name of the last folder in my basedir path in Ant?

Tags: ant

Let's say my basedir = c:/projects/myapp/1.2

How can I get "1.2" in a property?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Check [this](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/basename.html) out.

```
<basename property="property.for.dirname" file="${basedir}"/>
```

Comment: <basename property="jar.filename" file="${lib.jarfile}"/>

will set jar.filename to myjar.jar, if lib.jarfile is defined as either a full-path filename (eg., /usr/local/lib/myjar.jar), a relative-path filename (eg., lib/myjar.jar), or a simple filename (eg., myjar.jar).

Comment: Nice. I didn't know this worked for both directories and files.