# Getting name of last folder from maven ${project.basedir}

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I have the same question for Maven that someone had about Ant ([How can I get the name of the last folder in my basedir path in Ant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178462/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-last-folder-in-my-basedir-path-in-ant)).

How do you get just the last directory name from the variable ${project.basedir}?

For example, if my pom.xml is in:

/home/me/project/pom.xml

Then ${project.basedir} = /home/me/project/

I want just the directory name 'project'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use: `${project.file.parentFile.name}`

How to work it out:

The `${project}` actually resolved to a [MavenProject](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html) object.  From there, you can just use bean properties to get the value you need.  In this case:

- use the `file` property (through [getFile()](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.0.3/maven-core/apidocs/org/apache/maven/project/MavenProject.html#getFile%28%29))
- use the `parentFile` property on [java.io.File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) (through [getParentFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParentFile%28%29))
- use the `name` property of the File to get just the name without path information (through [getName()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29))

---

(edit: after comment)

It's not a good idea to use properties for artifact IDs.  The `${project.file.parentFile.name}` property cannot be resolved when using it as part of artifactId, however some properties do work (`project.groupId` for the artifactId seems to work).

However, this is not recommended.  In fact, if you use any property for the artifact ID instead of a constant, you'll get a warning when you build your project:

```
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for <your groupID>:<your artifactID>:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'artifactId' contains an expression but should be a constant. @ <your groupID>:<your artifact ID>:1.0-SNAPSHOT, <basedir>/pom.xml, line 5, column 14
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
```

Comment: Hi,


For some reason this doesn't work as the artifactId. What I'm trying to do is set my artifactId to the name of the folder the pom.xml file is in.


It's interesting because ${project.basedir} is replaced with the complete path to the folder containing the pom.xml, but ${project.file} is not replaced and is taken to be the artifactId literally. E.g.:


<artifactId>${project.basedir}</artifactId> results in:
artifactId = /path/to/project/


Whereas:


<artifactId>${project.file}</artifactId> results in and error because artifactId is set to:
artifactId = ${project.file}

Comment: @Naijaba indeed, tried on the `artifactId` and it failed, but works when I used it on a configuration option in a plugin.  Though it might not be a good idea using such a pattern in the artifactId, as if someone else checks out your project to a different directory name the artifactId will end up being different.  It's usually a good idea to stick to plain strings for artifactId.

Comment: Super !  Thanks for that. I have been trying to figure out a good way of naming multiple different versions of the same project based on the directory I have it checked out into, so that I can load them all into one Eclipse workspace. Turns out this worked perfectly:  ${project.file.parentFile.parentFile.name}.  Thanks !

Comment: If anyone cares, I did get this to work by removing the eclipse plugin projectNameTemplate tag completely and adding a simple property at the project level:   eclipse.projectNameTemplate>${project.file.parentFile.parentFile.name}-[artifactId]</eclipse.projectNameTemplate>

Comment: For anyone visiting this old answer: It seems that Maven 3 doesn't support this, but requires `pomFile` instead of `file`, so `${project.pomFile.parentFile.name}`, and also allows the simpler `${project.projectDirectory.name}`.  Found through https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.5.2/maven-model/apidocs/org/apache/maven/model/Model.html.